# routing to the targeted page with react-router-dom not working

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

I am trying to route to the targeted page after login success . 
1. At first i have tried with setting setState and redirecting on reder method.
if result is true on login

```
if (res) {
  this.setState({
    referrer: targetPage,
  });
}
```

and rendering like

```
const { referrer } = this.state;
    if (referrer) {
      return <Redirect to={referrer} />;
    }
```

2. I have also tried with withRouter HOC like

   if (res) {
         this.props.history.push(targetPage);
       }

   export default withRouter(withStyles(styles)(LoginView));
3. Also trid with

   this.props.history.goForward();

still cant find the solution

Comment: Please explain what is not working? Do you get an error? Please show the entire render method. What is the value of targetPage?

Comment: @RonF the problem is it is not redirecting to the target page provided, targetpage will have targeted page slug like '/checkoutpage' . I may be wrong but if the state will change then the render method is invoked and when the render method will receive the 'referrer' then it will redirect to that referrer (it is returned at the begining), also tried with this.props.history.push() method but sitll not redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `this.props.history.push()`.

I have also faced the same error. Or you can use alternative as well:

```
window.location = "http://www.example.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution from the official documentation 

on signInUser function set the state to redirectToReferrer as true

```
signInUser = async () => {
    const { email, password } = this.state;

    const res = await this.props.loginUser(email, password);

    if (res === true) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        redirectToReferrer: true,
      }));
    }
  };
```

And in render method.....

```
    const { redirectToReferrer } = this.state;
    let { from } = this.props.location.state || {
      from: { pathname: '/checkOutOrder' },
    };

    if (redirectToReferrer) return <Redirect to={from} />;
```